# Azure DevOps Pipeline - YAML formatting error?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, formatting, yaml, devops

Would anyone know how to solve the following error?

```
# Starter pipeline
- task: CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'aws_test'
    regionName: 'us-east-1'
    stackName: 'test'
    templateSource: 'url'
    templateUrl: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lizrice/5889f33511aab739d873cb622688317e/raw/c2ba38eb72b350fec28b50df0d8f74b51e1a68e8/vpc-fargate.yaml'
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml
trigger:
- main
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

The error I get on azure devops & yaml lint

```
Other Errors
2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
    /azure-pipelines-1.yml (Line: 2, Col: 1): A sequence was not expected
    /azure-pipelines-1.yml: (Line: 13, Col: 1, Idx: 461) - (Line: 13, Col: 1, Idx: 461): While parsing a block collection, did not find expected '-' indicator.
```

It appears on YAML Lint the error is "fixed" when I add 3 spaces in front of line 2 but azure devops will still throw a related error for the same line but other column.

Wondering if anyone has encountered this error before as I didn't really enter any YAML code myself, but used the editor + other GUI assistants within azure devops to create this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the YAML documentation. You have a `task` (i.e. the first thing in the file) **outside** of a scope in which it's valid, which would be under `steps`.

The YAML editor does not guarantee syntactically valid YAML. You're better off using a more robust editor like Visual Studio Code with the Azure Pipelines extension.